# How to count the nodes on a binary tree?

Tags: induction, trees

I need to give an inductive definition of the function $nodecount(t)$, which will determine the number of internal nodes in a binary tree $t$.

I understand the concept of both inductive definitions, and binary trees, but don't understand how that can be combined to give a definition of a function that will traverse the tree while counting the nodes - it just makes me think of a programming related solution (i.e. if current is a leaf then stop searching that branch, else continue searching and increment the count value).

How should I approach such a problem using purely inductive definitions?

Comment: How do you define "inductive function"?

Comment: Do you really mean "internal" nodes?  I didn't notice that at first.  An internal node is one that has no children.

Comment: Yes, really mean internal nodes. Does that mean only the nodes which have two branches linking to two leafs should be counted?

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** Count internal nodes instead of nodes.

The internal node count is 1 + the internal node count of the left subtree + the internal node count of the right subtree.  The basis is that the node count of a node with no child is $0$.

Comment: But I'm unsure how you go about getting the node count on the left and right subtrees.

Comment: It's a recursive function, which is what I understood you to mean.  Basically, you can compute the node count of a binary tree if can compute it for smaller trees.

Comment: How do you go about declaring a recursive function inductively though, everything I can find online is super confusing.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "declaring a recursive function inductively."  Are you writing a computer program?

Comment: I'm not. I'm trying to write a inductive definition of the `nodecount` function. So the inductive definition will have a base case, an inductive case and a external case that defines how the function works.

Comment: What is an external case?  I'm not familiar with this terminology at all.